# Spring Cloud Function input type lost when request has no body

Tags: spring-cloud-function

I've written a function using Spring Cloud Function that has an optional request body.  Everything works when the body has content but, if there's no content, the input to the function becomes `LinkedMultiValueMap` and the response object is wrapped in an array.

I've created a minimal function and test to illustrate the problem but, although I can imagine why the input type becomes `LinkedMultiValueMap` when no content is provided, it feels like a bug.  Is it a bug or am I just doing something wrong?

Also, what is the possible reason for the response to be wrapped in an array when there is no request body?

This is my minimal function

```
@Bean
Function<String, Integer> letterCount() {
    return value -> StringUtils.isEmpty(value) ? 0 : value.length();
}
```

and this is my test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@FunctionalSpringBootTest
public class LetterCountTestInt extends FunctionTestBase {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLetterCount() throws Exception {

        //final String input = "blah";
        final String input = "";

        final MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/letterCount")
                                               .content(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                                               .headers(createHttpHeaders()))
                                           .andReturn();

        mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(content().string(String.valueOf(input.length())));
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace I get when I do not provide content in the request body

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
at c.a.b.p.LetterCountTestInt.testLetterCount(LetterCountTestInt.java:46)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at org.springframework.cloud.function.core.FluxFunction.lambda$apply$0(FluxFunction.java:47)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxJust.java:99)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollectList.java:90)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:70)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable.subscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:63)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:59)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3694)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$DeferredResultSubscriber.connect(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:440)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler.handleValue(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:155)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:139)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
at c.a.b.p.LetterCountTestInt.testLetterCount(LetterCountTestInt.java:41)
... 31 more
```

Comment: Benjamin, this does appear to be something we should look at. Could you please raise an issue in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues and link to this post?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Sure, I'll add an issue.  Do I need to sign the Pivotal CLA before I do that?

Comment: Not for raising the issue, only for submitting PRs

Comment: Just to close the loop, this has been addressed https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/274